# Thermistor is more sensitive than metals

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, material-science, electronics

Can anybody tell me, why a [thermistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) is much more sensitive at temperature variation than a metal?

Comment: Did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor?

Comment: Also compare thermistors with RTDs; see http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3643/en/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: Its also not clear. By 'metal' did you mean thermocouple junctions or PRT's? And did you mean to say "more sensitive in measuring temperature".